# PHP: Zend Server on VM guest, Zend Studio on host, debugging is very slow

Tags: php, virtualbox, remote-debugging, zend-studio, zend-server

I have the following configuration running: 
The host is a MacOSX Lion system running a guest Debian 6 Server in an Oracle VirtualBox environment.

The Debian server runs Zend Server. The host has Zend Studio installed. The source code is located on the guest and its folder is shared via samba with the host.

In Zend Studio I added the project "from existing sources", using the connected samba share directory. Debugging works but is really really slow, practically unusable.

I already tried to bind the samba daemon to a host only network interface in virtual box and I also tried to locate the sources in a native VirtualBox shared folder. Even though sources lied on the host together with zend studio, I noticed no change in speed.

I tried searching google, but nobody seems to have a similar configuration and I wonder how other people work with a zend server installation in a virtual machine.

Edit: The virtual machine is connected to the host via network bridge setting in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last thing I tried was creating a remote sync project, which means that local files are synchronized with the guest system. File mapping was set up, but nothing changed. Debugging was still slow.

The solution was: Zend Studio added the IP address of my local tun0 device to 
Preference | PHP | Debug | Installed Debuggers | Zend Debugger | Configure
so requests probably went through the VPN tunnel. After removing this IP address from configuration, everything works fine.